# Textmate, exclude file (types?) from project search

Tags: macos, development-environment, textmate, text-editor

In TextMate, when I apple-shift-F to search my project, I have to wait through a spinning beach ball for it to tell me I don't have enough memory to load development.log .  How can I exclude (development).log from my project wide search?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the Preferences in Advanced there is a setting for file and folder patterns. To see how they may be used look [here](http://www.rngtng.com/2009/06/18/pimp-my-textmate-how-to-speed-up-search-load/).